# Was Jobs being sarcastic when he said he liked Hertzfeld?

Tags: character, analysis, steve-jobs

About 3/4 through *Steve Jobs (2015)*, before the iMac launch, Andy Hertzfeld argues with Steve Jobs about paying for Lisa's tuition. At the end of it, Steve says he's indifferent to people disliking him, so Andy says he's always disliked Steve. Steve replies "Really? I've always liked you a lot."

Just wondering what people thought about that scene. As sarcasm, it perfectly matches the serpent-tongued Jobs we've seen throughout the whole movie, but as a serious statement, it shows his indifference to others and biting candidness. If it was meant to be sincere, it's a really interesting look into what Jobs considers a "friendly" relationship, and would explain a lot of his actions towards his friends/family.

Was he sarcastic, or not?

Comment: @TK-421 It seems like the line added make this question too opinion based.